# My PHP 7 code will not work

Tags: php, html, xml

To those who have already installed PHP 7, and it works fine when you give PHP 7 code, please check my PHP 7 code and tell me if it works with you, (this code came from a book.) if it does not work then tell me how I could fix it, then if it does work, then tell me what else I have to install or do.
This is the PHP 7 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Luke Reports | Home </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$url = 'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment';
$xml =
simplexml_load_file( $url ) or die( 'Unalble to load data!');
include( 'includes/rss-footer.html');
foreach( $xml->channel->item as $item){
echo '<a href="'.item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a>';
echo '<br><small>'.$item->pubDate.'</small><br>';
echo $item->description.'<hr>';}
include( 'includes/rss-footer.html');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So I will highly appreciate it if you comment *or* Answer.

Thanks, Luke

Comment: How about *you* run your code and *tell us* what isn't working?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this is a parse error question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them and should be closed as a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: I just get a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code, you forget a '$' on line 13 as PHP told me:

> ***Parse error***: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';' in **/var/www/html/MYPATH/test.php** on line **13**"

It's `echo '<a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a>';`

Make sure you activated a [verbose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php#845025) PHP for debugging.